# Как отсортировать в jade элементы по спискам?

Tags: jade, шаблонизаторы

Есть такой массив объектов:

`categories: [{
        link: "#cat1",
        name: "Категория1",
      },{
        link: "#cat2",
        name: "Категория2",
      },{
        link: "#cat3",
        name: "Категория3",
      },{
        link: "#cat4",
        name: "Категория4",
      },{
        link: "#cat5",
        name: "Категория5",
      },{
        link: "#cat6",
        name: "Категория6",
      },{
        link: "#cat7",
        name: "Категория7",
      },{
        link: "#cat8",
        name: "Категория8",
      },{
        link: "#cat9",
        name: "Категория9",
      }]`

Как прогнать его через jade что-бы на выходе я имел списки в каждом из которых по 4 элемента и в последнем все оставшееся? ( как в этом примере должно получить два полных списка по 4 элемент и один неполный с одним элементов).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для организации первых двух списков циклы от 0 до 3 и от 4 до 7 соответственно и берите элементы массива по индексу. Jade прекрасно работает с JavaScript в своих шаблонах. Последний элемент получите по индексу 8.